# How to put the key for image encryption using AES Algorithm

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric, pgp

I'm newbie in java. I already have a code for AES algorithm for image encryption. My problem is I just want to add the key for my encrypt image and only the person I give the key can only decrypt the image example such as symmetric encryption, md5,pgp or anything else you all should suggest me for use as the key. Here is my code

```
package crypto;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author fIZI/Z47
 */
public class ImageCrypto extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ImageCrypto
     */
    public ImageCrypto() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        file_path.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(file_path.getText());
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Z47\\Desktop\\Encrypt Image.jpg");
            byte k[]="FiZi1701NuLl5252".getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");
            Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outStream, enc);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while((read=file.read(buf))!=-1){
                cos.write(buf,0,read);
            }
            file.close();
            outStream.flush();
            cos.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The image was encrypted successfully !");
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(file_path.getText());
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Z47\\Desktop\\Decrypt Image.jpg");
            byte k[]="FiZi1701NuLl5252".getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");
            Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            enc.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outStream, enc);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while((read=file.read(buf))!=-1){
                cos.write(buf,0,read);
            }
            file.close();
            outStream.flush();
            cos.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success! your image was decrypted. Click OK to preview the image.");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll, FileProtocolHandler "+"C:\\Users\\Z47\\Desktop\\Decrypt Image.jpg");
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }                                        

    private void file_pathActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageCrypto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageCrypto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageCrypto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageCrypto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ImageCrypto().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField file_path;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Btw, I'm using netbeans in JFrame and running GUI. Can anyone show full code for the key? by combine with my coding.

Comment: AES is a symmetric cipher. Since you've tagged this also with [public-key-encryption], I assume you know the distinction. I guess, you have your answer now. There are lots of examples. Didn't any of those fit your needs?

Comment: I had. Public key source code, but I don't know how to combine it with my image encryption coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to add the key for my encrypt image and only the person I
>   give the key can only decrypt the image

In your code your secret key is `byte[] k`.

If you want to securely send that to the recipient along with the encrypted image you might want to consider using an asymmetric key encryption algorithm to encrypt your secret key.

In practice, you would use the recipient's public key to encrypt the key used in the AES algorithm. Only they can decrypt that key in order to decrypt the message.

Comment: Sorry sir, i didn't catch what you said. For more detail, can you show a code for example?

Comment: I'm afraid your question wasn't very clear. You said that you wanted to "add the key for my encrypt image" - I was just pointing out that `byte[] k` was your key.

If you want to send that to someone, then you would probably be looking at using PGP. Encrypt your AES key using the recipient's private  key.

Comment: Well, thanks for you explanation just now. I fully understand now what I need to edit a code. If you have a link for PGP source code for that it would be nice. By the way thanks for the quick response and thanks a lot for helping. :D

Comment: No problem @JohnU2. You might want to take a look at Bouncy Castle - https://www.bouncycastle.org/